# htaccess redirect specific IP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect some IPs to a error.php . Ofc I don't want redirects from error.php to itself, so I excluded that. Bottom line, i don't figure it out where i'm wrong.

In this one i'm redirecting to google. But still failing.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^yyy\.yyy\.yyy\.yyy
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/error\.php [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://google.com [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using a negative lookahead?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^yyy\.yyy\.yyy\.yyy
RewriteRule ^(?!error\.php) http://google.com [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```